# Processing sketch not working on web

Tags: html, css, processing, processing.js

I have multiple processing projects up that are working great on my website, however I have two sketches in particular that do not work and don't display anything except small blank windows. The only similarity between the two that I can find is that they both require arrow keys to work, but besides that there are no similarities. You can inspect element to check the code, I can't seem to figure out why they are not working, any help would be greatly appreciated.
http://willhay.io/processing/crazy/ and
http://willhay.io/processing/MazeRunner/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a peak at the JavaScript Console in your browser's developer tools.
You should spot this:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
processing.min.js:18 Processing.js: Unable to execute pjs sketch.
processing.min.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: size is not a function
```

Perhaps the pages are attempting to initialise the Processing sketches before the document is fully loaded and the ProcessingJS library is ready.
Try doing that when the page is fully loaded to be on the safe side

Comment: I decided to delete one of them, and with the other one I deleted everything relating to size and it works great now thanks for the help.

Comment: Cool, glad your worked it out. Feel free to vote/mark the answer if it was useful ;) The Table class probably could be done in plain javascript. For a simpler interaction between Processing syntax and plain javascript, check out [P5.js](http://p5js.org/). You might like it if you need more js/html/css control. It doesn't support all the Processing features, but it looks promising